# How do I make a code with for loop inside while?

Tags: python, indexing, while-loop

I want to return the two indexes that have the biggest difference, while the minimum is on the left of the max.
Here's my code:

```
def get_buy_sell_dates(price_list):
   min = 0
   max = -1
   while min < (max + len(price_list)):
       for i in range(1, len(price_list)-1):
           if price_list[min] > price_list[i]:
               min = i
           if price_list[max] < price_list[-i-1]:
               max = -i-1
   return (min,max + len(price_list))
```

But for the list `[7,10,1,3,6,4]`it returns `(2, 1)` instead of (2, 4)

Answer (score 0):

This bit of code should work, however it is kind of slow for larger lists.

```
def get_buy_sell_dates2(price_list):
    locmax=-90
    mini=0
    maxi=0
    for i,ele in enumerate(price_list[:-1]):
        templ=[x - ele for x in price_list[i+1:]]
        lmax=max(templ)
        if lmax > locmax:
            locmax=lmax
            mini=i
            maxi=templ.index(lmax)+i+1
    return mini,maxi,locmax
```

Comment: You're right it's not O(n) more like O(n*(n+1)/2) ,and therefore O(n²) ,because each loop will loop over index-1 times the list.

Answer (score 0):

Go with two nested for-loops. For each value in the list, you'll loop through the values to the right. You can make it faster by skipping values where the next value is lower/greater. Obviously, if the value immediately following the minimum that you're checking is lower than what you're checking, you don't need to check the current value. Likewise in reverse for the maximums. I'm sure there are a lot of other optimizations you could add.

```
def get_buy_sell_dates(price_list):
    max_diff = 0
    max_diff_min = 0
    max_diff_max = -1
    for i in range(len(price_list)):
        ix = min(len(price_list) - 1, i + 1)
        if price_list[ix] >= price_list[i]:
            for n in range(ix, len(price_list)):
                nx = min(len(price_list) - 1, n + 1)
                if price_list[n] >= price_list[nx]:
                    diff = price_list[n] - price_list[i]
                    if diff > max_diff:
                        max_diff = diff
                        max_diff_min = i
                        max_diff_max = n
    if max_diff > 0:
        return (max_diff_min, max_diff_max)
    else:
        return None
```